# jquery resizable do not drag panel-footer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize

When I apply resizable in the panel and try resize to down, panel-footer does not come with the panel.

Is there some way to solve this problem?

The code is:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="resizable">
    <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
</div>

<script>
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        handles: "s"
    });
</script>
```

best regards!

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/unnqmnd8/1/)

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI?

Comment: yes, i used  jQuery UI, and bootstrap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make `.panel-footer` fixed to bottom

```
.dashboard_panel .panel-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/amrana83/rjk6q80g/1/

Comment: Thanks very helpful, thats its